# Queue becomes corrupted sometimes

Tags: c#, .net, queue

I'm running a heavily multithreaded program and seeing some weird behavior. I'll try to explain the architecture a little bit below first.

The application basically has an array of queues of size 30. Each queue in the array in being processed by a thread. An external ome outside thread will keep adding entities into the array of queues based on mod of an id.

Eg: if entity id=100 it will go into the 100%30 = 10th queue

The problem I'm facing is sometimes an entity of id=100 is added into the queue but the processing thread dequeues a totally different entity but belonging to the same queue. e

Eg: external thread enqueues entity id=50 which goes into the 20th queue but the thread dequeues and entity with id=80

This only happens in the production environment and is not able to be simulated in anyway. It happens infrequently without any sort of trigger like after application restart.

I suspect that this could be happening because I'm not using any locks when enqueing/dequeing causing a data corruption.

Would like to know if anyone has faced a similar problem before or any advice on ways to avoid this. Adding locks is one way forward but I would like to confirm the source of the problem before I move to that.

Comment: Do the threads that dequeue the entities use any sort of logic or do they directly dequeue based upon the assign Queue?

Comment: @bit, there is no logic in dequeing

Answer (score 5):

> I suspect that this could be happening because I'm not using any locks
>   when enqueing/dequeing causing a data corruption.

Yes, it is a source of data races. If your multiple threads are producing and consuming object on common, unprotected data structures, effects such as those you describe will randomly appear. Having data races "occurring more in production" is typical since you are using code that is more optimized, on faster machines, and often with more threads, increasing the likelihood of data races.

Protect each access to common structures with lock mechanism (e.g. [Monitors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx)). MSDN provides also multiple tutorials on [Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx).

Eventually, as already noted by @Ronan, consider using the collections from `System.Collections.Concurrent` : their access is already thread safe, and they are optimized for multithreaded scenarios, making your job far easier.

**EDIT:**
When performance matters, always consider profiling both approaches (using manual protected collections vs collections from `System.Collections.Concurrent`)

Comment: They are optimized for specific kinds of multithreaded scenarios. A `ConcurrentQueue<T>` can be far slower than a `Queue<T>` with a lock around it when you have a mixed use scenario with producers and consumers on the same threads; it's exaggerated even more in multi-core systems.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray do you have an alternative recommendation for how to address this (it seems like there's a lack of detail to make architectural recommendations...)

Comment: @TetsujinnoOni I definitely would go with quantdev's recommendation. I would also give the standard "Get a book on threading." type response. Locking is generally pretty fast and if it's not, then specialized lock free load balanced or priority queues (what he's trying to achieve to achieve I would guess) are extremely difficult to implement correctly but are possible alternatives. Profiling is a good way to determine where your bottleneck is and I am betting it's not lock contention.

Comment: Going back to this thread after ages... I still haven't been able to determine the problem. Profiling sounds like a way a forward but it is not an easy option for me as the issue occurs only in a production environment and profiling there is not an option. But still I'd like to try in another environment to see if I can find any patterns. @MichaelJ.Gray any tools that you recommend for profiling .Net 4.5 apps?

Answer (score 1):

You say you're not using any locks, are you using the Queue class? If so you should be using the [ConcurrentQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class for those scenarios, it is in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace

Comment: Essentially a link only answer. -1 until an explanation is given for why the `Queue` class isn't safe for use in concurrent environments without locks.

Comment: Seems to be self answering to me, the name of the class and the namespace in which it is makes it obvious?

Comment: I don't consider it useful on its own. It provides no explanation as to why the original code is wrong in the first place and does not present a standalone solution that anyone can use. If someone doesn't understand locking mechanisms and why it's important, then your answer is probably going to get overlooked and not help as many as it could. If your goal is to help people out, then why not improve it? You're almost there anyway. All I am doing is telling you why I chose to down-vote you; it's a common courtesy to provide explanations for down-votes on stackoverflow and I have given you that.